# I'm trying to install the compiler on the linux server

Tags: linux, gcc

When I try to install compiler in linux , I'm getting following error.

```
$ yum install -y gcc
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security, subscription-
              : manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
There was an error communicating with RHN.
RHN Satellite or RHN Classic support will be disabled.
Error communicating with server. The message was:
Unable to connect to the host and port specified
```

please help me I don't know what to do now. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It looks like the main problem is that it cannot connect to the Red Hat server to get updates.  It may be an internet connection issue, or that you have not yet registered the system to Red Hat Subscription Management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this solution from RedHat site helps: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/253273

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the error which you're receiving is because of your `RedHat` system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Manager! It is obvious from the error message also.

Actually, redhat is one of the strict organisations which insists you to get subscribed to them before officially downloading packages from their website! If you haven't,you need to! If you'd earlier,probably your subscription period has ended!

If you want to download it from the official RedHat server,you won't be able to do in this way without subscribing to them! Kindly subscribe or follow other means to download GCC,i.e., directly downloading from [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html) website or from [SOFTPEDIA---GCC(Linux)](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Compilers/GCC-641.shtml)!

Answer (score 0):

For your information, I had this error when totally deleting my yum cache 6Server directory. To fix this, I reinstalled my machine. Probably there was a simpler solution I couldn't find.